# import a map variable from another file in go

Tags: go, import

I have a  main.go and need to import a map variable from another package.

my anotherfile.go is

```
package greet

var Selectorslist = make(map[string]string)
Selectorslist["coxxnfirmedCases"] = "dsj"
```

When i try to save this file, following error is getting.

> syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function bodygo

Why this error occurring?

Comment: Because in Go any non-declaration statements must be inside the functions.

Comment: can you give me correct code @demas

Comment: @akhilviswam if you want to provide a top level map variable with some initial data, either use a composite literal or use the `init` func. https://play.golang.com/p/7vt0UkpiKOZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in Go any non-declaration statements must be inside the functions. 
Try to import function, not variable:

```
func GetSelectorsList() map[string]string {
  var selectorslist = make(map[string]string)
  selectorslist["coxxnfirmedCases"] = "dsj"
  return selectorsList
}


func main() {
    data := GetSelectorslist()
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/htxzAJO83ci)

May be it will be better if you change name `Selectorslist` to `Selectorsmap`, because it is actually associative container, but not sequential one.

Or as @mkopriva said, you can use `init()` function:

```
var SomeData int

func init() {
    SomeData = 10
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SomeData)
}
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WN_OIt8AvwC)

Comment: missing function body go

Comment: @akhilviswam, I added playground link

Comment: @akhilviswam, sorry, I fixed the link